# javascript .replace and .trim not working in vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, replace, vue.js, trim

Hey guys so I wrote a vueapp and Im trying to use functions like .trim() and .replace to sanitize the data that comes into the form. However it doesnt seem to be working. I need those to validate the form. For example in almost all of the fields I want to trim out spaces and for the phoneNumber field I want to replace "(" and ")" and "-" with an empty string. as they type them. 
heres the code:

```
<?php ob_start();
session_start();

include('head.php');
include('header.php');
?>
    <div id="signUpFormContainer">
  <div id="signUpForm">

      <!--USERNAME-->
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <p v-show="usernameLength==true && usernameHasCap==true && usernameHasNum==true && userexist==false">Username* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
        <p v-show="userexist == true">Username* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Username Already Exists</span></i></p>
               <p v-show="userexist==true" class="error">We are sorry but that username already exists.</p>
        <p v-show="usernameLength==false && userName!='' && sub!=1 || usernameHasCap==false && sub!=1 && userName!='' && userexist==false || usernameHasNum==false && sub!=1 && userName!='' && userexist==false">Username* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Username must be at least 8 characters, Have a capital letter and contain a number</span></i></p>
        <p v-show='userName=="" && sub!="1" && userexist==false'>Username* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Username must be at least 8 characters, Have a capital letter and contain a number</span></i></p>
        <p v-show='sub==1 && usernameLength==false && userexist==false || sub==1 && usernameHasNum==false &&  userexist==false || sub==1 && usernameHasCap==false && userexist==false'>Username* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Username must be at least 8 characters, have a capital letter and contain a number</span></i></p>

      <input v-model="userName" placeholder="Username" v-on:focus="showusernamerequirements">
                 <ul v-show="disunamer==true">
          <li v-show="usernameLength==false || userName==''">Must contain at least 8 characters</li>
             <li v-show="usernameHasCap==false">Must contain capital letter</li>
             <li v-show="usernameHasNum==false">Must contain number</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <!--END USERNAME-->

      <!--PASSWORD-->
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <p v-show='passwordLengthMet==true && passwordHasCap==true && passwordHasNum==true'>Password* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
        <p v-show='passwordLengthMet==false && password!="" && sub!=1 || passwordHasCap==false && sub!=1 && password!="" || passwordHasNum==false && sub!=1 && password!="" '>Password* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Password must be at least 8 characters, Have a capital letter and contain a number</span></i></p>
        <p v-show='password=="" && sub!="1"'>Password* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Password must be at least 8 characters, Have a capital letter and contain a number</span></i></p>
        <p v-show='sub==1 && passwordLengthMet==false || sub==1 && passwordHasNum==false || sub==1 && passwordHasCap==false'>Password* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Password must be at least 8 characters, have a capital letter and contain a number</span></i></p>
         <input type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="Password" v-on:focus="showpasswordrequirements">
         <ul v-show="dispassr==true">
          <li v-show="passwordLengthMet==false || password==''">Must contain at least 8 characters</li>
             <li v-show="passwordHasCap==false">Must contain capital letter</li>
             <li v-show="passwordHasNum==false">Must contain number</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <!--END PASSWORD-->

      <!--PASSWORDS MATCH-->
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <p v-show="passwordsMatch==true && password!=''">Confirm Password* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Passwords Match</p>
         <p v-show="passwordsMatch==false && password!='' || sub==1 && confirmPassword=='' || confirmPassword!='' && password==''">Confirm Password* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Please make sure passwords match</span></i></p>
          <p v-show="password=='' && sub==0 && confirmPassword==''">Confirm Password* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Confirm your password please</span></i></p>
     <input type="password" v-model="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" v-on:focus="showconfirmpasswordrequirements">
        <ul v-show="disconfr==true">
        <li class="blue" v-show="passwordsMatch==false">Please be sure your passwords match</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <!--END PASSWORDS MATCH-->

      <!--FIRSTNAME-->
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <p v-show="validFirstname==true">First name* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
      <p v-show="validFirstname==false && sub==1">First Name* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Please enter your firstname</span></i></p>
        <p v-show='validFirstname==false && sub!="1"'>First Name* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Please enter a firstname</span></i></p>
        <input v-model="firstName" placeholder="Firstname" v-on:focus="showfirstnamerequirements">
        <ul v-show='disfnamer==true'>
        <li v-show="validFirstname==false">Please enter a firstname</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <!--END FISTNAME-->

      <!--LASTNAME-->
    <div class="inputDiv">
      <p v-show="validLastname==true">Last Name* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
      <p v-show="validLastname==false && sub==1">Last Name* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Please enter your lastname</span></i></p>
        <p v-show='validLastname==false && sub!="1"'>Last Name* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Please enter a lastname</span></i></p>
        <input v-model="lastName" placeholder="Last name" v-on:focus="showlastnamerequirements">
        <ul v-show='dislnamer==true'>
        <li v-show="validLastname==false">Please enter a lastname</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <!--END LASTNAME-->

      <!--EMAIL-->
    <div class="inputDiv">
        <p v-show="validEmail==true">Email* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
        <p v-show="validEmail==false && email!=='' || email=='' && sub==1">Email* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Please enter a valid email</span></i></p>
        <p v-show="email=='' && sub==0">Email* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Please enter a valid email</span></i></p>
      <input v-model="email" placeholder="jchang@example.com" v-on:focus="showemailrequirements">
        <ul v-show='disemailr==true'>
        <li v-show="validEmail==false">Please enter a valid email</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        <!--END EMAIL-->

        <!--PHONE -->
        <div class="inputDiv">
        <p v-show="phoneLength==true && phoneHasNum==true && phoneNumber!=''">Phone* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
        <p v-show="phoneLength==false && phoneNumber!='' || phoneHasNum==false && phoneNumber!='' || phoneNumber=='' && sub==1">Phone* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Phone Number must have at least 10 numbers and have no letters, parenthis or dashes</span></i></p>
        <p v-show="phoneNumber=='' && sub==0">Phone* <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Phone Number must have at least 10 numbers and have no letters it cannot contain parenthis or dashes</span></i></p>
        <input v-model="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number 1234567890" v-on:focus="showphonenumberrequirements" id="phoneNumber">
        <ul v-show="disphoner==true">
        <li v-show="phoneLength==false">Phone number must be 10 numbers long</li>
        <li v-show="phoneHasNum==false || phoneNumber==''"> Phone number must contain only numbers</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        <!--END PHONE-->

        <!--COMPANY NAME-->
        <div class="inputDiv">
            <p v-show="validCompanyName==true">Company Name* <i class="fa fa-check-circle success"></i> Valid</p>
            <p v-show="validCompanyName==false && companyName!='' || companyName==false && companyName=='' && sub==1">Company Name* <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle tooltip error"><span class="tooltiptext">Please enter your company name</span></i></p>
            <p v-show="companyName=='' && sub==0">Company Name*  <i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip" style="color:darkblue;"><span class="tooltiptext blue" style="background-color:darkblue;">Please enter your company name</span></i></p>
            <input v-model="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" v-on:focus="showcompanynamerequirements">
            <ul v-show="discompr==true">
            <li v-show="validCompanyName==false">Please enter your company name</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
        <!--END COMPANY NAME-->

    <div class="inputButton">
      <input v-on:click="makeAccount" id="addButton" type="button" value="Sign Up"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
<div id="footerContainer"></div>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#signUpForm',
  data: {
    userName: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    sub: '',
    dispassr: '',
    disconfr: '',
    disfnamer: '',
    dislnamer: '',
    disemailr: '',
    disunamer: '',
    disphoner: '',
    discompr: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    companyName: '',
    userexist: ''
  },
  computed: {
    passwordsMatch: function() {
      if(this.password == this.confirmPassword && this.confirmPassword.trim()!='') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    passwordLengthMet: function() {
      if(this.password.trim().length >= 8) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    passwordHasCap: function(){
      if(/[A-Z]/.test(this.password)){return true;} else{return false;}         
    },
    passwordHasNum: function(){
      if(/[\d]/.test(this.password)){return true;} else{return false;}  
    },
    validEmail: function() {
      var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
      if (!reg.test(this.email)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
      validLastname: function() {
          if(this.lastName.trim().length<1){return false;} else {return true;}
      },
      validFirstname: function() {
       if(this.firstName.trim().length<1){return false;} else{return true;}   
      },
      usernameLength: function(){
          if(this.userName.trim().length>=8){return true;} else{return false;}
      },
      usernameHasCap: function(){
        if(/[A-Z]/.test(this.userName)){return true;} else{return false;}
      },
      usernameHasNum: function(){
      if(/[\d]/.test(this.userName)){return true;} else{return false;}  
    },
      validCompanyName: function(){
          if(this.companyName.trim().length<1){return false;} else{return true;}
      },
      phoneHasNum: function(){
          this.phoneNumber.replace("(","");
          this.phoneNumber.replace(")","");
          this.phoneNumber.replace("-","");
          if(isNaN(this.phoneNumber)){return false;} else {return true;}
      },
      phoneLength: function(){
          if(this.phoneNumber.trim().length==10){return true;} else{return false;}
      }
  },
  created: function() {
      this.userexist=false;
  },
  watch: {
  },
  methods: {
    makeAccount: function() {
        this.sub=1;
      if(this.usernameLength && this.usernameHasCap && this.usernameHasNum && this.validFirstname && this.validLastname && this.validEmail && this.passwordHasCap && this.passwordHasNum && this.passwordLengthMet && this.passwordsMatch && this.validCompanyName && this.phoneNumber!='' && this.phoneHasNum && this.phoneLength) {
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify({
          userName: this.userName,
          firstName: this.firstName,
          lastName: this.lastName,
          password: this.password,
          email: this.email,
          phoneNumber: this.phoneNumber,
          companyName: this.companyName
        });
        $.ajax({
          url: 'makeAccount.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'post',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: jsonString,
            error: function(data){
              alert('error');
                window.location.href='error.php';
            },
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
              alert('success');
              this.userexist=data.userexist;
              if(this.userexist==false){window.location.href='successfullycreated.php?userName='+this.userName;}
          }.bind(this)
        });
    }
    },
      showpasswordrequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.dispassr=true;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disunamer=false;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      },
      showconfirmpasswordrequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=true;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disunamer=false;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      },
      showfirstnamerequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=true;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disunamer=false;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      },
      showlastnamerequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=true;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disunamer=false;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      },
      showemailrequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=true;
          this.disunamer=false;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      }, 
      showusernamerequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.userexist=0;
          this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disunamer=true;
          this.disphoner=false;
          this.discompr=false;
      }, 
      showphonenumberrequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.disphoner=true;
           this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disunamer=false;
          this.discompr=false;
    },
      showcompanynamerequirements: function(){
          this.sub=0;
          this.disphoner=false;
           this.dispassr=false;
          this.disconfr=false;
          this.disfnamer=false;
          this.dislnamer=false;
          this.disemailr=false;
          this.disunamer=false;
          this.discompr=true;
      }
    }
  });

</script>
<?php include('foot.php');?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have Vue automatically trim the input's value by changing the input's markup from `v-model` to `v-model.trim`. For example: `v-model.trim="password"`. You can view the documentation, here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#trim

To remove non-digit characters from the phone number as the user types, add a listener to the input field to listen to the `input` event:

```
<input v-model="phoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number 1234567890" v-on:focus="showphonenumberrequirements" id="phoneNumber" v-on:input="removeNonDigitCharacters">
```

Then, implement the event handler like:

```
methods: {

  removeNonDigitCharacters: function() {
    this.phoneNumber = this.phoneNumber.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
  }

}
```

See the Pen [Vue phone  number](https://codepen.io/dansterrett/pen/GdoPOo/) by Dan Sterrett ([@dansterrett](https://codepen.io/dansterrett)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Trim works but your removeNonDigitCharacters does not

Comment: can you send me a fiddle